# Combine two rows in single column with same Id

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is currently how I return values. but I want to combine rows that have the same Id's.  I tried using the unpivot but I couldn't get it to work.
here's my query:

```
   SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 
            ID,
            Setup, 
            Message
    FROM myViewHere
)
AS tempTable
UNPIVOT
(
    [Message]
    FOR Test
    IN (ID, Setup) 
) AS PVT
```

This is the result of **myViewHere**

```
    |ID | Setup  | Message  |
    |---|--------|----------|
    | 1 | Header | myHeader |
    |---|--------|----------|
    | 1 | Footer | myFooter |
```

What I want to achieve:

```
    |ID | Header   | Footer   |
    |---|----------|----------|
    | 1 | myHeader | myFooter |
    |---|----------|----------|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical pivot case https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Assumed table name is "source"

```
SELECT ID, [Header], [Footer]
FROM source
PIVOT
( max(Message) FOR Setup IN ([Header], [Footer])) p;
```

See test on sqlfeedle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7635f/7

Comment: weird that in sql fiddle, i tried it my own and it works.. but when I do it in SQL, the output is wrong.. well from my side, the source is a view..

Comment: I got it now, it was because of other unique values columns in the view.. but for my question this solves the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can change your view query to be like below

```
  SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 
            ID,
            Setup, 
            Message
    FROM myViewHere
)
AS tempTable
UNPIVOT
(
    [Message]
    FOR Test
    IN (ID, Setup) 
) AS UNPVT
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Message]) 
    FOR [Setup] 
    IN ([Header], [Footer])
)PVT
```

Comment: The type of column "Setup" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.